# Inserting PHP variables into a SQL insert query with Oracle

Tags: php, oracle

I am extremely new to php and have what is hopefully a simple question that I just can't quite seem to find an answer for.

I need to insert a new row into my database based on information from a form filled out by the user. After a lot of testing I believe the problem is with the SQL statement itself.

Here's what I have:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users 
          VALUES('$userID',
                 '$firstName',
                 '$lastName',
                 '$password')";
```

I have confirmed that a proper connection to the database has been made, but the information is still not added to the table. I have done a fair amount of research and can't seem to find an answer that fits. I originally thought it was just an issue with my quotes, but after a lot of fiddling with them I still couldn't get it to work.

Edit: Sorry I am very new to stack overflow and I seem to have left out so important information.
 `$conn = oci_connect($dbuser, $dbpass, $dbconn);

```
            $query = "INSERT INTO users 
                      VALUES('$userID',
                             '$firstName',
                             '$lastName',
                             '$password')";

            $stid = oci_parse($conn,$query);
            oci_execute($stid,OCI_DEFAULT);

            oci_free_statement($stid);
            oci_close($conn); `
```

And here is the table in question:

`CREATE TABLE users
(userID varchar(15) NOT NULL,
 fName  varchar(15),
 lName varchar(15),
 password varchar(15) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (userID));`

Comment: What does your table structure look like ?

Comment: Are you executing the query? Just assigning it to a string doesn't execute it.

Comment: If you're executing the query, are you checking for errors? What error are you getting? Also, try `echo $query` to see the full query, and then try pasting it into SQL*Plus to see if it executes.

Comment: Just a totally unrelated nit, I would always specify the column names with a `INSERT VALUES` statement to make it more robust against exchanged or added columns.

Answer (score 0):

Before closing the connection, you must commit your DML operations:

```
oci_commit($conn);
```